# Is a variable swap guaranteed to be atomic in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, atomic, cpython

With reference to the following link: http://docs.python.org/faq/library.html#what-kinds-of-global-value-mutation-are-thread-safe

I wanted to know if the following:

```
(x, y) = (y, x)
```

will be guaranteed atomic in cPython. (x and y are both python variables)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Let's see:

```
>>> x = 1
>>> y = 2
>>> def swap_xy():
...   global x, y
...   (x, y) = (y, x)
... 
>>> dis.dis(swap_xy)
  3           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (y)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (x)
              6 ROT_TWO             
              7 STORE_GLOBAL             1 (x)
             10 STORE_GLOBAL             0 (y)
             13 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
```

It doesn't appear that they're atomic: the values of x and y could be changed by another thread between the `LOAD_GLOBAL` bytecodes, before or after the `ROT_TWO`, and between the `STORE_GLOBAL` bytecodes.

If you want to swap two variables atomically, you'll need a lock or a mutex.

For those desiring empirical proof:

```
>>> def swap_xy_repeatedly():
...   while 1:
...     swap_xy()
...     if x == y:
...       # If all swaps are atomic, there will never be a time when x == y.
...       # (of course, this depends on "if x == y" being atomic, which it isn't;
...       #  but if "if x == y" isn't atomic, what hope have we for the more complex
...       #  "x, y = y, x"?)
...       print 'non-atomic swap detected'
...       break
... 
>>> t1 = threading.Thread(target=swap_xy_repeatedly)
>>> t2 = threading.Thread(target=swap_xy_repeatedly)
>>> t1.start()
>>> t2.start()
>>> non-atomic swap detected
```

Answer (score 4):

<del>Yes, yes it will.</del>

[I stand corrected](http://www.techlists.org/archives/programming/pythonlist/2002-03/msg04632.shtml).

> Kragen Sitaker 
>   writes:
>
> > Someone recommended using the idiom
> >
> > ```
> > spam, eggs = eggs, spam
> > ```
> >
> > to get a thread-safe swap.  Does this really work? (...)
> >     So if this thread loses control anywhere between the first LOAD_FAST
> >     and the last STORE_FAST, a value could get stored by another thread
> >     into "b" which would then be lost.  There isn't anything keeping this
> >     from happening, is there?
>
> Nope.  In general not even a simple
>   assignment is necessarily thread safe
>   since performing the assignment may
>   invoke special methods on an object
>   which themselves may require a number
>   of operations.  **Hopefully the object
>   will have internally locked its
>   "state" values, but that's not always
>   the case.**
>
> But it's really dictated by what
>   "thread safety" means in a particular
>   application, because to my mind there
>   are many levels of granularity of such
>   safety so it's hard to talk about
>   "thread safety".  About the only thing
>   the Python interpreter is going to
>   give you for free is that a built-in
>   data type should be safe from internal
>   corruption even with native threading.
>   In other words if two threads have
>   `a=0xff` and `a=0xff00`, a will end up
>   with one or the other, but not
>   accidentally `0xffff` as might be
>   possible in some other languages if a
>   isn't protected.
>
> With that said, **Python also tends to
>   execute in such a fashion that you can
>   get away with an awful lot without
>   formal locking, if you're willing to
>   live on the edge a bit and have
>   implied dependencies on the actual
>   objects in use**.  There was a decent
>   discussion along those lines here in
>   c.l.p a while back - search
>   groups.google.com for the "Critical
>   sections and mutexes" thread among
>   others.
>
> Personally, **I explicitly lock shared
>   state** (or use constructs designed for
>   exchanging shared information properly
>   amongst threads, such as `Queue.Queue`)
>   in any multi-threaded application.  To
>   my mind it's the best protection
>   against maintenance and evolution down
>   the road.
>
> --
>   -- [David](http://www.techlists.org/archives/programming/pythonlist/2002-03/msg04632.shtml)

Comment: Why? GIL? The disassembly doesn't suggest atomicity (see @jemfinch's answer).

Comment: (BTW, the above comment is *not* a rhetorical question.)

Comment: @Kenny: it was a misunderstanding of my part as how tuple unpacking worked on the low level.