# Python - Difference between variable value declaration on Fibonacci function

Tags: python, fibonacci, variable-declaration

I'm kind of beginner in python. I was looking at one the types to make a fibonacci function,

```
def fib(n):
a=0
b=1
while a<n:
    print a
    a,b=b,a+b
```

and I saw the a,b=b,a+b declaration. So, I thought a=b and b=a+b were the same to a,b=a,b+a, so I changed the function for it to be like this:

```
def fib(n):
a=0
b=1
while a<n:
    print a
    a=b
    b=a+b
```

and I thought it would be right, but when I executed the program, I got a different output. Can someone explain to me the difference between those two types of declaration?

Thanks, anyway.

Comment: see [Is a variable swap guaranteed to be atomic in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2623086)

Answer (score 1):

`b, a+b` creates a tuple containing those two values. Then `a, b = ...` unpacks the tuple and assigns its values to the variables. In your code however you overwrite the value of a first, so the second line uses the new value.

```
a, b = b, a + b
```

is roughly equal to:

```
tmp = a
a = b
b = tmp + b
```

Answer (score 1):

When Python executes

```
a,b = b, a+b
```

it [evaluates the right-hand side first](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order), then unpacks the tuple and assigns the values to `a` and `b`. Notice that `a+b` on the right-hand side is using the **old** values for `a`.

When Python executes

```
a=b
b=a+b
```

it evaluates `b` and assigns its value to `a`.
Then it evaluates `a+b` and assigns that value to `b`. Notice now that `a+b` is using the **new** value for `a`.

Answer (score 0):

That syntax simultaneously assigns new values to `a` and `b` based on the current values.  The reason it's not equivalent is that when you write the two separate statements, the second assignment uses the *new* value of `a` instead of the *old* value of `a`.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, a isn't updated to take the value of b until the entire line has been evaluated -- so b is actually a + b.

In you example, you've already set a to b, so the last line (b=a+b) could just as easily be b=b+b.

It's all in the order in which things are evaluated.