# How to verify if one step is Atomic operation in python or now

Tags: python

Is operation like `a,b=1,2` atomic ?

Some background of my issue :I am working with signal . which are being raised from some external process. Here i want to avoid the cases when signal is being captured between setting `a=1 and b=2`. Is there any way to achieve this ?

Is there any way to check if given step is atomic or not ?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623086/is-a-variable-swap-guaranteed-to-be-atomic-in-python

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is not atomic because it takes multiple bytecode instructions to assign to multiple names and it doesn't take long to confirm it experimentally:

```
import signal

a = 1
b = 2

def handler(sig, trace):
    print a, b

def main():
    global a, b
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)
    while True:
        a, b = 3, 4
        a, b = 1, 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

$ python atom.py
^C3 4
^C3 4
^C1 2
^C1 2
^C3 4
^C1 2
^C1 2
^C1 2
^C1 2
^C1 4 <<<< inconsistent state
```

In this particular case, if you want two values to change atomically, you can get away with assignment to tuple and accessing its elements in the signal handler. Looking at disassembly:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 2
>>> c = (1, 2)
>>> def foo():
...     global a, b
...     a, b = 1, 2
... 
>>> def bar():
...     global c
...     c = (1, 2)
... 
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  3           0 LOAD_CONST               3 ((1, 2))
              3 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
              6 STORE_GLOBAL             0 (a)
              9 STORE_GLOBAL             1 (b)
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             15 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(bar)
  3           0 LOAD_CONST               3 ((1, 2))
              3 STORE_GLOBAL             0 (c)
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

No matter how complex the value is, assignment to a variable (or `dict` entry, or object field) is a single atomic store operation.

Comment: this is exactly what i wanted to check ..

Comment: I think this answer is great. For future reference and visitors, someone (you? :-)) should take the time and add a detailed explanation of what is happening behind the scenes that leads to this inconsistent state (also incorporating information from the other answer, that `STORE_FAST (a)` is executed before `STORE_FAST (b)`).

Answer (score 4):

No, the sequence assignment is not atomic. Just take a look at the byte code:

```
>>> def unpack():
        a,b=1,2

>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(unpack)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               3 ((1, 2))
              3 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
              6 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
              9 STORE_FAST               1 (b)
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             15 RETURN_VALUE
```

The assignment takes multiple opcodes to evaluate the tuple and store the result in variables.

Comment: so is it like this step contains 6 atomic operations ?? or this is of 2 atomic operation

Comment: A single opcode instruction is atomic. A different thread can change the value in consideration anytime between any 2 opcodes.