# multiple variable assignment in python in single line

Tags: python, expression

I have following lines of code. I am a newbie to python.

```
def fibo(n):
 a, b = 0,1
 while a < n:
    print a,
    a,b=b,a+b
n = raw_input("Enter a no:")
fibo(int(n))
```

I am not able to understand following code.

```
a,b=b,a+b
```

Is it equivalent to following?

```
a = b
b = a+b
```

I tried that, but didn't get expected results. I understand that its a multiple value assignment in a single line. please correct me if I am missing anything.

Comment: yep, you're correct.

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21047524/how-does-swapping-of-members-in-the-python-tuples-a-b-b-a-work-internally and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623086/is-a-variable-swap-guaranteed-to-be-atomic-in-python