# instantiating two classes with references to each other

Tags: python

I have two classes, `B` and `C`.

I want to instantiate `B` with `C` reference and `C` with `B` reference.

I could add a setter method, but was wondering if I can do it in the `__init__` stage or any other elegant ways

Comment: What do you mean *precisely*? It *sounds* pretty straightforward... But you should *definitely not* use getters and setters in Python.

Comment: `a = A(); b = B(); a.b, b.a = b, a`

Comment: ok how ?. How can I pass a reference of C to B before C is even created.

Comment: Have B create an instance of C itself

Comment: @Adam - interesting !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible within `__init__` directly due to a chicken and egg situation.  However, it is possible in one assignment statement:

```
>>> class A:
...     pass
... 
>>> class B:
...     pass
... 
>>> a, b = b.a, a.b = A(), B()
>>> a.b is b
True
>>> b.a is a
True
```

This relies on the fact that Python evaluates assignments left to right.

It is [not thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2623086/674039); if you need to guarantee that the references exist in a threaded application then you'll want to use a mutex to handle the possible race conditions.  The GIL works at the opcode level, which is a finer-grained resolution than lines of Python code.

Comment: It also does not pass the references to both constructors simultaneously, which is of course impossible.

Comment: @JoshLee that's splitting hairs to an absurd degree. Even atomic operations don't do two things simultaneously.

Comment: @AdamSmith Just to clarify. The specific question asked is not possible, but there are various creative ways to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in `__init__` if you make one of the class initializers take an object of the other class:

```
>>> class B:
...    def __init__(self):
...       self.c = C(self)
...
>>> class C:
...    def __init__(self, b):
...       self.b = b
...
>>> b = B()
>>> c = b.c
>>> b.c
<__main__.C object at 0x107a4f6d8>
>>> b.c.b.c
<__main__.C object at 0x107a4f6d8>
>>> b.c.b.c.b
<__main__.B object at 0x107a60e80>
>>> b
<__main__.B object at 0x107a60e80>
>>> c
<__main__.C object at 0x107a4f6d8>
>>> c.b
<__main__.B object at 0x107a60e80>
>>> b.c
<__main__.C object at 0x107a4f6d8>
>>> b.c.b.c
<__main__.C object at 0x107a4f6d8>
>>> c.b.c.b
<__main__.B object at 0x107a60e80>
```

Or even without any arguments to `__init__`:

```
>>> class B:
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.c = C()
...         self.c.b = self
...
>>> class C:
...     pass
...
>>> b = B()
>>> c = b.c
>>> b
<__main__.B object at 0x10835c048>
>>> c
<__main__.C object at 0x1085ccac8>
>>> b.c
<__main__.C object at 0x1085ccac8>
>>> c.b
<__main__.B object at 0x10835c048>
>>> b.c.b.c.b
<__main__.B object at 0x10835c048>
```